# Apply a class AND an attribute selector

Tags: css

I want to style this element:

```
<input class="myslider" type="range" value="20">
```

This is working:

```
input[class*="myslider"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 2px;
}
```

But this is not working:

```
.myslider input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 2px;
}
```

Why can't I apply a class selector **and** an attribute selector?

Comment: Because you are selecting an input inside .myslider

Comment: `.myslider input[type=range]` - This means `myslider` is a parent of input. Which it isn't in this case.

Comment: Thx. Does that mean direct parent, or could it be any ancestor?

Comment: The input *could* be nested inside other elements, and `.myslider input {}` would still work - providing there wasn't a more specific selector over-riding it.

Answer (score 3):

The selector you're looking for is

```
input.myslider[type=range]
```

Your current code looks for children elements and doesn't target the appropriate element.

Answer (score 2):

Becuase you are selecting input inside `.mySlider`. Try this:

```
.myslider[type='range'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 2px;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ55Q/)</kbd>